# Detect URL parameter change in React

Tags: reactjs

React is not detecting when the last parameter in the url changes. if I reload the page it works.

I´m using **"react-router-dom": "^5.0.1"**

the "router"

```
<Router>
    <PrivateRoute path="/users/:id" exact strict component={User}/>
</Router>
```

then. inside the **User** component I have a list of users and the details of the selected user

```
class User extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            userId: null,
            users: [{id: '1', name: 'john'}, {id: '2', name: 'mary'}]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.setState({'userId': id})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="users">
                    {this.state.users.map((user, index) => {
                        return (<Link to={`users/${user.id}`}  key={index}>{user.name}</Link>)      
                    })}
                </div>
                <pre className="details">{this.state.userId}</pre>          

            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default User;
```

when I select a different user the url changes but **this.state.userid** remains the same

UPDATE:

I resolved it with

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { id } = nextProps.match.params;
    this.setState({'userId': id}
}
```

but I´m getting this warning.

```
Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use.
```

React Hooks or die ?

Comment: Looks like state only changes on mount `this.setState({'userId': id})` within `componentDidMount`. Clicking your link will not remount the user component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ComponentDidMount` is called once (when the component mounts), so if does not matter if you change the route, the lifecycle will not be called again.

In order to achieve what you want I recommend you to use another lifecycle like (`ComponentDidUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps`) or start using hooks, in your case [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Or if it is simple, use the prop directly in the render method.

UPDATE:

This should do the trick:

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.state.userId !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.setState({ userId: this.props.match.params.id });
    }
  }
```

componentDidUpdate [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is still safe to use and is invoked immediately after updating occurs.

Comment: actually I´m using this.state.userId to call a service to get user details. do I have to convert this class component to a function component in order to do it with hooks? sorry I didn't investigate hooks at all yet.

Comment: Yes, in order to use hooks you must convert class components to function components. 

It is not necessary that you migrate to react hooks, in your projects you can have a mix of class components with lifecycle methods and functional components with hooks and it will work, but hooks makes your life easier. With hooks you just focus on effects (for instance, what should I do when certain data changes), not what lifecycle should I use.

Answer (score 1):

ComponentDidMount is called only once when the component mounts. When you change the URL, your component may re-render due to react-router, but the component is already mounted and will not run that code again.

I think in this case you can just reference this.props.match.params.id in the render method directly, rather than setting it as state. Alternatively you could use componentDidUpdate along with a check for which props changed to reset the state.

Answer (score 1):

> To Detect changes in **URL** or **Dynamic URL** or **URL query params** or **detect changes on query params** on **back button** use componentDidUpdate

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    //to detect dynamic URL params according to above question
    if (this.state.userId !== this.props.match.params.id) {
       //your code here
    }
    //to detect URL query params update and backbutton
    if (this.props.location.search !== prevProps.location.search) {
      //your code here
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the case**, you are facing such issue due to **redirect** within in your website.

**Try to use < a > instead of < Link >**

```
<a> does not retain the previous state.

<Link> retain the previous state to improve performance but cousing trouble in such situation.
```